# THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture marked for update but image is incomplete Using Aframe

Tags: javascript, laravel, three.js, aframe

I am using A frame in laravel to display boxes.I get this message the first time i open my website THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture marked for update but image is incomplete  and  dont see all the boxes. However when i reload (the page is cashed ) it appears normally with no errors.Can you please help me figure out what's wrong

```
@foreach($hotspots[0] as $hotspot)
<a-box position="" color="tomato" height="20" width="20" depth="20" shadow event-set__click="_event: click; color:black" change-color-on-hover
    id="hotspot-{{$hotspot->id}}" data-link-to="{{$hotspot->link_to}}" data-link-from="{{$hotspot->link_from}}"></a-box>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Where is the texture in your page?

Comment: can u please explain what you mean by texture? ( i am using default red color to color the boxes)